# Writing simple manuscript with special character

Tags: pandoc, tex

I am on scientific linux 7 (rhel7). I am writing a simply formatted manuscript in markdown, and using pandoc to convert to pdf. I have a simple sty file, but I get the same errors with or without it:

```
\usepackage[vmargin=1in,hmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
```

Everything looks great, but I cannot seem to include the character: µ. When I add it and build I get the error:

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:µ not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

I read online that I should use `--latex-engine=xelatex` so I tried that and I get:

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `eu1enc.def' not found.
(fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.
```

I can find no useful information about this file online, and I don't see any package that will install it:

```
$ yum provides eu1enc.def
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.vcu.edu
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmforge-extras: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmforge-testing: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * sl: ftp.scientificlinux.org
 * sl-extras: ftp.scientificlinux.org
 * sl-fastbugs: ftp.scientificlinux.org
 * sl-security: ftp.scientificlinux.org
No matches found
$
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `yum install 'tex(eu1enc.def)'` ? (Straight from google).

Comment: I think I'm oversimplifying the question, but is this a problem with `µ != $\mu$`, meaning specifically that you've included the `µ` symbol directly in your markdown, and LaTex is freaking out about it?